# How can i use ng-hide if like.length === 0?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application. I can succefully output true or false by writing `{{liked.length === 0}}` . It alterates between true and false as desired.

If  i use it in ng-show/hide however:

```
  <any ng-show="liked.length === 0"  />
```

It always shows the tag ng-show, never the ng-hide. Why?

Comment: What do you mean 'it always show the tag'?

Comment: Do you actually have an ng-hide="liked.length === 0" element?

Answer (score 0):

With `ng-show`, the element will get `display: none;` style if the expression evaluates to false. With `ng-hide`, the element will get `display: none;` style if the expression evaluates to true.